# how can validate the time in a if condition in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, terminal

i hope that you can help me to give me ideas about my code, because i do not know how can i do for validate if the script enter two times followed in 20 minutes in the if condition.

```
rc=0
while [ $rc -ne 1 ]; do
do
  ping 192.168.1.89

  if [ "$?" -ne "0" ]; then
     sleep 600 # this are 10 minutes
     # here i need to validate if this script enters two times followed in 20 minutes
     continue

  else
     continue
  fi

done
```

any help will be welcome, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are monitoring an IP for loss of connectivity, and you want to take action if two pings 10 minutes apart fail.  To achieve this you can just use a counter.

```
failures=0
rc=0
while [ $rc -ne 1 ]; do
do
  ping 192.168.1.89
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
     ((failures++))
     echo Ping failures: $failures
     if (( failures < 2 )); then
         sleep 600
     else
         echo Max failures hit
     fi
  else
     failures=0
  fi
done
```

You might need to modify the ping commandline to send a maximum number of pings (e.g. use `-c 3` to send a maximum of 3).  And you might want to redirect ping output to `/dev/null`.

Comment: ok, i forgot to put the -c 1 option for ping, so let me try this code and i'll comment if this is what i looking for, thanks

Comment: i tried, and that's works perfectly for me, thanks a lot #paddy

Comment: You can change the loop to `while true; do` since rc is never changed after it is set to 0.